# FATAL EXCEPTION: MQTT Rec: One of RECEIVER_EXPORTED or RECEIVER_NOT_EXPORTED should be specified when a receiver isn't being registered exclusively

Tags: android, broadcastreceiver, mqtt, mobile-development, android-14

FATAL EXCEPTION: MQTT Rec:
One of RECEIVER_EXPORTED or RECEIVER_NOT_EXPORTED should be specified when a receiver isn't being registered exclusively for system broadcasts

I am getting fatal exception while receiving the data from MQTT
I have changed my all legacy code to new code where I am passing RECEIVER_NOT_EXPORTED but still, I am facing the same issue.

```
ContextCompat.registerReceiver(this,mMessageReceiver,
                new IntentFilter(AppConstants.INTENT_FILTERS.DASHBOARD_MESSAGE),
                ContextCompat.RECEIVER_NOT_EXPORTED);
```

The same code is working fine in the below version of 14.

Can anyone please help me in this?

I have tried to pass RECEIVER_NOT_EXPORTED while registering Broadcast receiver but still, I am facing the same issue

Answer (score 0):

Instead of using contextCompat use `this` if it is an activity or use `requireContext()` if it is a fragment.

Then use it like this.

```
requireContext().registerReceiver(mMessageReceiver,
                new IntentFilter(AppConstants.INTENT_FILTERS.DASHBOARD_MESSAGE),RECEIVER_NOT_EXPORTED);
```

**Make sure you import the correct one. You need to import the context one.**

[image]

You can even add an sdk check.

```
if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= Build.VERSION_CODES.TIRAMISU) {
     requireContext().registerReceiver(mMessageReceiver,
                new IntentFilter(AppConstants.INTENT_FILTERS.DASHBOARD_MESSAGE),RECEIVER_NOT_EXPORTED);
}else {
    requireContext().registerReceiver(mMessageReceiver,
                new IntentFilter(AppConstants.INTENT_FILTERS.DASHBOARD_MESSAGE));
}
```